# Why is pam_env.conf ignored after I su into root user?

Tags: arch-linux, environment-variables, login, pam, su

I'm trying to do:

`su -l`

and set environment variables like PAGER without success.  How can I achieve this?

This is what I have in `/etc/pam.d/login`:

```
auth       required     pam_securetty.so
auth       requisite    pam_nologin.so
auth       include      system-local-login
account    include      system-local-login
session    include      system-local-login
session    required     pam_env.so readenv=1 user_readenv=1 envfile=/etc/locale.conf
```

Comment: What OS is this? According to this link, your options are named differently. https://linux.die.net/man/8/pam_env

Comment: I'm using Arch...

Comment: Turn your debug on and post what it's outputting

Comment: Done, but I don't know how to read the log, can you help me?  I'm kind of a newbie on this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> This is what I have in `/etc/pam.d/login`:

Unless you modified */etc/pam.d/su-l* to include this file, this is file is not relevant as `su -l` only [mimics](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Su#Login_shell) `login` by switching the home directory and resetting some environment variables.

The default */etc/pam.d/su-l* (which is used by `su -l` [on Arch Linux](https://github.com/karelzak/util-linux/blob/master/Documentation/PAM-configuration.txt)) should look like this:

```
#%PAM-1.0
auth        sufficient  pam_rootok.so
# Uncomment the following line to implicitly trust users in the "wheel" group.
#auth       sufficient  pam_wheel.so trust use_uid
# Uncomment the following line to require a user to be in the "wheel" group.
#auth       required    pam_wheel.so use_uid
auth        required    pam_unix.so
account     required    pam_unix.so
session     required    pam_unix.so
```

If you add `session    required   pam_env.so` at the end of this file, you can (by default) add KEY=VAL pairs in the file */etc/environment* to set [environment variables](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Environment_variables).

Comment: Excellent, I ended up modifying su-l.  Thank you!